# Adding div dynamically but issues with input type radio

Tags: html, jquery, css, radio-button

I am using a `<a>` on click of which i am cloning a div. In div i have two radio buttons with same name.

Now the problem is when i select one radio option and clone the div the next two radio buttons come with same name and selected radio button from last div got unselected.

```js
$('.addMore').on('click', function() {
  $('.addMoreDiv:last').clone().insertAfter('.addMoreDiv:last');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="addMoreDiv">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optradio">Radio 1
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optradio">Radio 2
  </label>
</div>

<a href="#" class="addMore">Add More</a>
```

I tried updating name according to length but didn't work and name updates after addition of div.

Is there any option so that when i add new div it comes with different names also the selection of last div will not effect?

Comment: `clone()` method just add one more copy of the element. The element's attributes remain the exact same. But you are not changing the `name` attribute in your code .

Comment: What about saving the result of the clone in a `var`, edit the name of it, and then reinsert it?

Comment: @sailens could u share an example of it how to change the variable

Comment: @lucky i am changing the name with javascript bt as clone method already insert a new element after that the name is changed so the problem still exists..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @sailens; we need to change the `name` of radio group so that it will be considered as totally newer set of radio buttons. We can achieve it in following way:

```js
var count = 0;
$('.addMore').on('click', function() {
  var clonedDiv = $('.addMoreDiv:last').clone();
  clonedDiv.find("input[type=radio]").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("name","optradio_"+count);
  });
  count++;
  clonedDiv.insertAfter('.addMoreDiv:last');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="addMoreDiv">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optradio">Radio 1
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optradio">Radio 2
  </label>
</div>

<a href="#" class="addMore">Add More</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.addMore').on('click', function() {
  $('.addMoreDiv:last').clone().insertAfter('.addMoreDiv:last');
  $('.addMoreDiv').each(function(i, v) {
    $(this).find('input').attr('name', 'optradio' + i)

  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="addMoreDiv">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optradio">Radio 1
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optradio">Radio 2
  </label>
</div>

<a href="#" class="addMore">Add More</a>
```

After cloning and inserting go through all the div and find the input and change the `attr name` this will make the radio button separate from each other on every div

Comment: You did the same thing...check your own result problem is still there

Comment: @GauravAggarwal when i select radio button each are independent. when you select radio1  in first line it wont deselect the other radio button that is what the OP wants

Comment: Bt if you select any radio and then click addmore the selection disappears.

Comment: @GauravAggarwal i see i didnt saw it.. it is because it renames the name attr every click. i will update it to change only the name attr of cloned element

Answer (score 0):

Find the below code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="addMoreDiv">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optradio">Radio 1
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optradio">Radio 2
  </label>
</div>

<a href="#" class="addMore">Add More</a>
```

Script to create new div with different radio names:

```
$('.addMore').on('click', function() {
  // total number of div's, to create unique name for `radio`
  var n = $('.addMoreDiv').length;
  var lastdiv = $('.addMoreDiv:last');
  var newdiv = lastdiv.clone();

  // changing the name for `radio`
  newdiv.find('input[type="radio"]').prop('name', 'optradio'+n);

  // adding after changing names.
  newdiv.insertAfter(lastdiv);

});
```

Comment: As i told in my question before changing name the div is added so the same problem exists.

Comment: just swap the `newdiv.insertAfter(lastdiv);` and below line then it will change the names before adding like i done in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var clone = '';

  var count = 0;
  $('.addMore').on('click', function() {

    clone += '<div class="addMoreDiv">';
      clone += '<label>';
        clone += '<input type="radio" name="optradio'+count+'">Radio 1';
      clone += '</label>';
      clone += '<label>';
        clone += '<input type="radio" name="optradio'+count+'">Radio 2';
      clone += '</label>';
    clone += '</div>';

    $('.addMoreDiv').after(clone);

    count++;
  });
```

Still facing problem. please comment below.

Comment: Yeah this will work bt the html i shared was just an example bt the actual structure is very big i cant write all the string for it.